# Site provisioning: add web part to page

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I would like to present a document library on the home page (`default.aspx`) of a classic SPO site.
What I would do with hand is to edit the page - add web part - apps - select the document library.

I exported this web part, added a few placeholders to the dynamic properties and I am able to add it to a new site, but I have difficulties with one property:

```
<property name="ListName" type="string">#ListID#</property>
```

Now, I can query the list id with

```
$listid = (Get-PnPList | where {$_.Title -eq $listname}).ID
```

and substitute the `#ListID#` placeholder in the xml, but isn't there any better way to achieve this, without extra rounds?  Can I maybe put this in the provisioning template?

Edit:
Site provisioning done like:

```
New-PnPWeb -Title $Title -Url $SubSiteUrl -Template $Template -InheritNavigation   #default STS#0
Connect-PnPOnline $url -Credentials $credential
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $template
```

The "Document" library is made by the default STS#0 template, I don't see, how I could get the library ID. The PnP template is almost empty.

Comment: in provisioning template xml, simply replace the listid with `<property name="ListName" type="string">{{listid:Documents}}</property>` and it will work, did you try this ?

Comment: Hm, will check this, thanks. Is this kind of use of the engine documented?

Comment: yes, its documented. [Here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/ProvisioningEngineTokens.md) is a full list of supported tokens

Comment: Hm, can I use the tokens in an exported webpart too? With `Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl $page -Path $webpart -ZoneId $zone -ZoneIndex $index` I get a _List does not exist._ error.

Comment: no, it doesnt work with `PnPWebPartToWebPartPage` command as it is a standalone commandlet and not part of provisioning engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `{{listid:ListName}}` token instead of hard-coding the GUID.

When you use this token , the provisioning engine will fix the placeholder with the actual value of the List ID.

For example, if your list/document library name is `Documents`, use `{{listid:Documents}}`. Put the below line of code in your template xml file and then PnP will fix it for you:

```
<property name="ListName" type="string">{{listid:Documents}}</property>
```

Reference - [Provisioning Engine tokens](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/ProvisioningEngineTokens.md)

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I use. The problem with SP Online and remote APIs is that you have no access to a strongly-typed XsltListView webpart object, so you're stuck importing an XML-based web part and swapping out the placeholders as you've done.

I don't know what your provisioning process is like, but the ones I use are typically fully automated WebJobs and the placeholder approach is pretty solid once the process is set up.

Comment: The process is still work in progress. My real problem is not with the placeholders. I know most of these in advance, so I can replace them in the template. But at the time of the provisioning, the list ID is not known, so I cannot fill it before I start the process. Instead, I need to go to the provisioned site, read it the id on the fly, manipulate my local file, and go back to site.

Comment: So, if the provisioned site is provisioned via code, you should be able to grab that ID in the same process.  Instead of manipulating a local file, read the file along with the tokens into a string, and do the token replacement on the string in memory.

Comment: I added the way I do the provisioning now to the question.